# R.* error in Notepadv3

Tags: android, eclipse

I just imported the Android tutorial solution Notepadv3.  I wanted to see it run.

As usual, I'm greeted with the inability to resolve R.

I searched for an import R line and see none.

I edited a line and saved. I closed and opened the application.

What do I do??

This seems to happen on every project.

(I have tried this with Eclipse Ganymede under Ubuntu 9.1 and Eclipse Helios under Windows 7.)

Answer (score 0):

> I searched for an import R line and see none.

`R.java` will be generated in the same package that is declared in the manifest. Usually, your code resides in that same package, and therefore a manual import of `R` is not needed.

> What do I do??

`R.java` will be created as part of the build process, in your project's `gen/` directory.

If you have automatic builds enabled, and `R.java` is not being built, check your Eclipse console for error messages, such as bad or missing resources.

If you do not have automatic builds enabled, do a build.

Every now and then, you will need to do a Project|Clean to clear out erroneous errors and force Eclipse and Android to rebuild your project from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @CommonsWare said, if after you do a `Project > Clean` and `R` is still not resolved, make sure you are importing your project's `R.java` and not `android.R.*`.

Comment: Thank you both.  This is an irritating issue.  I did a project > clean as well as checked for an import android.R line.  This is a continual frustration.  Console only gives me: [2011-02-21 17:06:34 - note_edit.xml] Unable to resolve dimension value "match_parent" in attribute "layout_width"

Answer (score 0):

check for errors in .xml files.Build may be failing because of these.